# Windows explorer only shows size of first disk in NAS

Tags: windows-explorer, nas

My Zyxel NSA325v2 NAS has two 6TB disks. Free space on disk1 is 4,91 TB, on disk2 4,48 TB.
In windows explorer both disks are displayed to have 4,48 TB free, so it is showing the free space of disk2 for both the disks. Disk 2 was mounted before disk 1 so I think it actually is showing the size of the first disk that was loaded. I dont know if this a problem of the NAS (the GUI of the NAS is showing the right free space) or windows explorer.
My NSA325v2 is still using smbv1 and will not be upgraded to smbv2 or later. Could that be the problem?

Comment: How are the disks organized on the NAS? Do you use RAID or JBOD? Is the share you’re accessing actually on a volume spanning both disks?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My configuration is JBOD. I have no shares that are spanned over two volumes.